# ijson fails with trailing garbage parse error

Tags: parse-error, ijson

```
for prefix, event, value in parser:
    print(prefix)
```

I get the following error after executing the above code , I dont understand what the error is.

ijson.common.IncompleteJSONError: parse error: trailing garbage
          nt":19485,"verified":false}} {"user_id":1408970940,"id":4496
                     (right here) ------^

Answer (score 13):

Seems you are trying to parse a JSON document with more than one top-level object, which is not standard. `ijson` allows for this though if you give the `multiple_values=True` flag to the method you are using.